# Sorting by line

Tags: c

If someone could help me find where i am going wrong, i have been working on this code for a long time but cannot get it right. 
It takes a linked list to be sorted by passing *head as head pointer. The output of that function should be the same linked list sorted in ascending order such that the header node will be the smallest value in the
list.

```
void sortByCount (struct lnode** head) {

    struct lnode* temp= (*head);
    struct lnode* temp2 = (*head);

    int i;
    int j;
    int counter = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = nodeGetNext(temp);
        counter++;
    }
    for( i = 1; i<counter; i++)
    {
        temp2=(*head);
        bool flag = false;
        for(j = 1; j<counter-i+1;j++)
        {
            if(countCmp(temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2))>0)
            {
                swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2));
            }
            if(countCmp(temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2))== 0 && (wordCmp(temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2))>0))
            {
                    swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2));
                    flag = true;                    
                    //continue; 
            }
        }
        temp2 = nodeGetNext(temp2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the code? For example is it a compile error or a crash, or incorrect output?

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal, compilable testcase so that we may correctly diagnose your problem. Minimal means "using only the bare essentials required to reproduce the problem". Compilable means "able to compile on our systems without guessing/filling in blanks or fixing basic typos". Your current testcase doesn't fulfill the "compilable" requirement.

Comment: You probably want `*head = something` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your loop:

```
        if(countCmp(temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2))>0)
        {
            swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2));
        }
        if(countCmp(temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2))== 0
           && (wordCmp(temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2))>0))
        {
                swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNext(temp2));
                flag = true;                    
                //continue; 
        }
```

If you decide to bubble up, and swap, then the second `if` check might choose to bubble up again (since the swap has happened, the next of `temp2` will have changed). This is probably not what you intended. Instead, you probably meant to do the second `if` check only if the first `if` check failed. This is normally accomplished by adding an `else` to the `if` statement.